# Return String formatted like a credit card number

Tags: java, string, formatting

I have a simple cardNumber String that I'm trying to Format for my System.out.ln

Here is the method that my System.out.ln calls

```
public String getCardNumber() 
{
    cardNumber = "0000 0000 0000 0000";
    return cardNumber;
}
```

but the made up part of cardNumber = "0000 0000 0000 0000"; is what I'm trying to format it like, so 12345678912345752 becomes 1234 5678 9124 5752

I've had a look at substring() and stuff but I can't see a simple way to go through every 4 characters and insert a space automatically.

Comment: What about `.substring()` confuses you?  What other "stuff" have you looked at?  Do you understand how string concatenation in Java works?

Comment: I've only used String concatenation for things like System.Out such as ("text" + "moretext"). But I can't figure out how to translate that across to a variable of String. I tried substring but all I could get that to do was display a certain amount of numbers or start from one index position and go to the next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to manually edit your string

```
        String input = "1234567891245752";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
           if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0) {
              result.append(" ");
            }

           result.append(input.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See what we're doing here is iterating over your string, and adding a whitespace in between every 4 characters.

Comment: This seems the best way to do it, I've never heard of StringBuilder before but I have successfully implemented it changing a few things around to reflect my code. 

http://i.imgur.com/CMfuaIl.png

Answer (score 2):

To add a space after every 4 characters in a 16 character string, do this.

```
String number = "1234123412341234";
number = number.substring(0,3) + " " + number.substring(4, 7) + " " + number.substring(8, 11) + " " + number.substring(12, number.length());
```

Comment: That worked and was the idea I had in mind with substring, but I wasn't sure on it because it's quite messy. Is there a way to for loop it so every 4 indexes up until number.length it inserts + " "?

Comment: You can change your last substring to `substring(12)` since that will give you a string that goes to the end of the String.

Comment: I was thinking something like this, although mine does not work


`public String getCardNumber() 
    {
      
        for (int i=0; i < cardNumber.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                cardNumber += " ";
            }
        }
        
        return cardNumber;
    }`

Comment: That's quite appropriate Ryan, if the string is always exactly 16 characters both exhibit the same behaviour but I would say this is likely better practice.

Answer (score 1):

try out the following method:

```
public String getNumberString() {
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0000,0000,0000,0000", symbols);
    return fmt.format(this.number);
}
```

Comment: this.number is primitive long;
the whole class could look like that:
    public final class CreditCard {
        private final long number;
        public CreditCard(final long number) {
            super();
            this.number = number;
        }
        public String getNumberString() {
            DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
            DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0000,0000,0000,0000", symbols);
            return fmt.format(this.number);
        }
    }